# touchSlider "mouseTouch: true" option won't work

Tags: slider

I am currently working on a slider, using [touchSlider](http://touchslider.com/), and it mouseTouch option won't work for me. 
Slider itself works fine, but not the mouseTouch option. 
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".touchslider").touchSlider({ mouseTouch: true });
});
```

and html:

```
        <div class="touchslider">
            <div class="touchslider-viewport" style="width:500px; height: 375px;overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid #f00;"><div>
                <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="img/3540115854_5d302001da.jpg" width="500" height="354" /></div>
                <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="img/3542680555_ea43d85e0a.jpg" width="500" height="354" /></div>
                <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="img/3540231388_f8ec22b549.jpg" width="500" height="354" /></div>
                <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="img/3546828250_6f91b64ba7.jpg" width="500" height="354" /></div>
            </div></div>

            <div>
                <span class="touchslider-prev">←</span>
                <span class="touchslider-nav-item touchslider-nav-item-current">1</span>
                <span class="touchslider-nav-item">2</span>
                <span class="touchslider-nav-item">3</span>
                <span class="touchslider-nav-item">4</span>
                <span class="touchslider-next">→</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the **same problem** when accessing the .html via my local file system using the **file-protocol**

```
file://pathtothehtml/touchslidertest.html
```

The problem **does not occur** when I accessing the .html using **http**

```
http://hostnametothehtml/touchslidertest.html
```

I used chrome,firefox and safari on MacOS - using http solved the problem on all of them.

#### cause analysis

The browser handle the results gathered using the file-protocol different to results gathered via the http.

*Careful: the following is only guessing, since I had not found anything about how any of the common browser handles the file-protocol.*

Maybe the browser supports drag&drop for the file-protocol. This support may override the event handling of the page interpreter in the browser - such that the drag event on the image does never reach the DOM-event handling routine for the page.